# merging two sets of data and figuring out which is new and which is old

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two sets of data with the same fields:

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| PK | myCDKey | DateCreated |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 |  131048 | 8/18/2014   |
|  2 |  131049 | 8/18/2014   |
|  3 |  131050 | 8/18/2014   |
|  4 |  131051 | 8/18/2014   |
|  5 |  131052 | 8/18/2014   |
|  6 |  131053 | 8/18/2014   |
|  7 |  131054 | 8/18/2014   |
|  8 |  131055 | 8/18/2014   |
|  9 |  131058 | 8/18/2014   |
| 10 |  131059 | 8/18/2014   |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

and

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| PK | myCDKey | DateCreated |
+----+---------+-------------+
| 11 |  131048 | 8/19/2014   |
| 12 |  131049 | 8/19/2014   |
| 13 |  131053 | 8/19/2014   |
| 14 |  131054 | 8/19/2014   |
| 15 |  131055 | 8/19/2014   |
| 16 |  131058 | 8/19/2014   |
| 17 |  131059 | 8/19/2014   |
| 18 |  111111 | 8/19/2014   |
| 19 |  222222 | 8/19/2014   |
| 20 |  333333 | 8/19/2014   |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

The output that I would like to have is something like this:

```
+----+---------+------------+
| PK | myCDKey | Delete/Add |
+----+---------+------------+
|  3 |  131050 | delete     |
|  4 |  131051 | delete     |
|  5 |  131052 | delete     |
| 18 |  111111 | add        |
| 19 |  222222 | add        |
| 20 |  333333 | add        |
+----+---------+------------+
```

The output shows me that when comparing the two dates, the most recent actions were that 3 of the CDs were deleted and 3 were added.

**Is there already an out of the box way to do this perhaps with the merge function?**

Thank you to @Linger for pointing out that I  should explain how we know that they were added/deleted.

> Added: if the myCDKey exists in the most recent date, but not the
>   previous date, then it is added.
>
> Deleted: if the myCDKey exists in the previous date, but not in the
>   most recent

**Please note that when comparing 2 data sets, we will ONLY have 2 dates (as in the example here we have only 8/18 and 8/19)**

Comment: How can we tell if they were added or deleted?  And what about all of the other `myCDKey`'s?  Why are they not in the output?

Comment: by the date. if the most recent date that myCDKey does not exist, then it was deleted

Comment: Could you full-outer join the two sets (on myCDKey) and use which PK is null to determine action? (i.e. if old PK is null, add. if new PK is null, delete. if both present, ignore)

Comment: @Captain that seems like a cool solution. could you show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3b601/14/0):

```
SELECT m1.PK, m1.myCDKey, 'delete' AS `DELETE/ADD`
FROM MyTable1 m1 
WHERE m1.myCDKey NOT IN 
(
   SELECT t2.myCDKey
   FROM MyTable2 t2
)
UNION
SELECT m2.PK, m2.myCDKey, 'add' AS `DELETE/ADD`
FROM MyTable2 m2
WHERE m2.myCDKey NOT IN 
(
   SELECT t1.myCDKey
   FROM MyTable1 t1
);
```

Or you could do something like ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3b601/27/0)):

```
SELECT m1.PK, m1.myCDKey, 'delete' AS `DELETE/ADD`
FROM MyTable1 m1 
LEFT JOIN MyTable2 m2 ON m1.myCDKey = m2.myCDKey 
WHERE m2.myCDKey IS NULL
UNION
SELECT m2.PK, m2.myCDKey, 'add' AS `DELETE/ADD`
FROM MyTable1 m1 
RIGHT JOIN MyTable2 m2 ON m1.myCDKey = m2.myCDKey 
WHERE m1.myCDKey IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

```
minus Tbl1 from Tbl2 : added records , add Delete/Add as 'add'
union
minus Tbl2 from Tbl1 : deleted records, add Delete/Add as 'delete'
```

use `except` in sql server

Comment: minus is oracle syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
select y.pk, x.mycdkey, 'delete' as delete_or_add
  from (select mycdkey
          from tbl1 except
                select mycdkey from tbl2
        ) x
  join tbl1 y
    on x.mycdkey = y.mycdkey
union all
select y.pk, x.mycdkey, 'add' as delete_or_add
  from (select mycdkey
          from tbl2 except
                select mycdkey from tbl1
        ) x
  join tbl2 y
    on x.mycdkey = y.mycdkey
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac1a7/6/0

Answer (score 1):

the version using a FULL JOIN would be:

```
select coalesce(m1.PK,m2.PK) PK
, coalesce(m1.myCDKey, m2.myCDKey) myCDKey
, case 
  when m1.PK is null then 'add' 
  when m2.PK is null then 'delete' else 'error' 
end as action
from MyTable1 m1
FULL OUTER JOIN MyTable2 m2 ON m1.myCDKey = m2.myCDKey 
WHERE m1.PK is null or m2.PK is null
```

The fiddle is here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c3b60/6/0)